# SVN error on XCode 4.4, commit 15k files

Tags: svn, commit, xcode4.4

since I've updated XCode to 4.4 it seems to behave quite weird with my svn repositories. When I try to commit any changes to a file it says I have 15570 files to commit, and of course,I can't commit any of the project files. If I uncheck all files (these files range from folders and files from my User folder, to the actual svn files of my projects) and then select to commit one of those it selects again all of the 15k files. I've tried to reinstall and tried with XCode 4.5 too but it's the same.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to delete your local repository and check it out again? Can you try to commit from the command line?

Comment: I deleted all the hidden .svn directories on my project and deleted the entire project from my repository. I then imported my project into the repository again. Checked it out. And nothing, it's the same

If I try to commit from command line it's OK, it's how I'm doing right now, but it's annoying to go command line each time I want to commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a while I realize that there was an extra repository on repositories tab in Organizer. It was my user folder, so it was versioning EVERYTHING inside it. I don't know how it was created but after deleting it everything went to normal. I'm surprisingly confused about that repository. I'm pretty sure I didn't create it so I wonder how it was created...